# Can't get post parameter in Golang from ajax request

Tags: ajax, go, post, go-gin

On the client side I have code:

```
    let response = await fetch('/getInfo', {
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({filename: "file.jpg"})
    });
```

Code on the server side:

```
    fmt.Println(c.PostForm("filename")) // empty
```

Why is it empty? How to get value of `c.PostForm("filename")`?

Comment: Your client is sending JSON, but your server is trying to decode a form. That obviously won't work.

Comment: How can I get that value then?

Comment: Either send it as form-encoded, or decode it as JSON. The key is that encoding and decoding must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code decodes JSON object from request body:

```
// Request is structure to encode request body
type Request struct {
    FileName string `json:"filename"`
}

// ServeHTTP is request handler
func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var req Request
    err := decoder.Decode(&req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        return
    }
    // process request
}
```